# Is there a possibility to specify length of array that comes from props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Is it possible to specify the length of the array that comes from `props` using type from `Typescript`?

We have an array of objects:

```
const arrayPassedViaProps = [
  { key: '1', label: 'Label 1', value: 9 },
  { key: '2', label: 'Label 2', value: 3 },
  { key: '3', label: 'Label 3', value: 3 },
  { key: '4', label: 'Label 4', value: 22 },
  { key: '5', label: 'Label 5', value: 1 }
]
```

I pass this array as `props` like this:

```
<DownlineProgress data={arrayPassedViaProps} />
```

Inside `DownlineProgress` component I defined a type:

```
type DownlineProgressBarProps = {
  data: {
    key: string
    label: string
    value: number
  }[]
}
```

I'm using this type with `props`

```
export const DownlineProgress = ({data}: DownlineProgressBarProps) => ...
```

I would like to be informed by Typescript when I'm passing props that the array doesn't have the correct length, it should contain TWO or THREE objects

How I can modify my `type` to achieve such behavior?

PS. currently I'm using `if` statement to check

```
if(data.length > 3 || data.length < 2){
  throw(`DownlineProgress need an array of length 2 or 3. You pass ${data.length}`)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the length of an array with [these custom types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40002#issue-677053879):

```
type TupleOf<T, N extends number> = N extends N ? number extends N ? T[] : _TupleOf<T, N, []> : never;
type _TupleOf<T, N extends number, R extends unknown[]> = R['length'] extends N ? R : _TupleOf<T, N, [T, ...R]>;
```

And then:

```
type DownlineProgressBarProps = {
  data: TupleOf<{
    key: string
    label: string
    value: number
  }, 2 | 3>
}
```

Comment: I try to implement this, and it seems to be fine inside the component :) 
But when I try to use this component somewhere like:
`<DownlineProgress data={testValuesProvided} />` the "data" word is underlined, and statement says:
`Type '{ key: string; label: string; value: number; }[]' is not assignable to type '[{ key: string; label: string; value: number; }, { key: ..... Target requires 3 element(s) but source may have fewer.`

Comment: This is expected behavior. If `DownlineProgress` can take  only arrays of length `2` or `3`, then `testValuesProvided` must fulfill this requirement. Putting there an array of any length should raise an error.

Comment: Your solution works, but there is a thing that I don't understand.
When I declare a variable and pass to it an array of length = 2 (should be ok) then I have an error.. BUT if I pass the same array directly to the props everything works fine

this is fine: 
`<DownlineProgress data={[{ key: 'kkks', label: 'Label 1', value: 9 },{ key: 'sdfsdf', label: 'Label 2', value: 3 }]}/>`

this causes an error:
`<DownlineProgress data={arrOfLenght2} />`

Comment: ok, now I see that TS can't assign array of object: `const arr: {
    key: string;
    label: string;
    value: number;
}[]` to our Tuple, should I type `arr` also? I mean, import our `DownlineProgressBarProps` and type every array that we will use as props ?? 
I know that I am wandering in the dark :D but I start learning TS last Thursday, so it's not even one week :)

Comment: By default TS tends to widen types, i.e. if you have `let arr = [1, 2];` its inferred type will be `number[]`, not `[number, number]`. You have to explicitly type any variable that you want to pass to `data` as a tuple of a given length to make it assignable to `data`.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers and patience! :) I will do like you said.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a pure TypeScript solution:**

```
interface Data {
    key: string;
    label: string;
    value: number;
}

// The following type should have two or three elements of type Data
type ArrayWithTwoOrThreeDataElements = [ Data, Data, Data? ];
```

In your case since in the props value you are expecting an object with a property named `data` of type Data, you can define the type of props as follow:

```
type DownlineProgressBarProps = [
    { data: Data }, 
    { data: Data },
    { data: Data }?
];
```

Naturally you can create a type for a single prop item if you want to avoid repeating the *data* property key:

```
interface Data {
    key: string;
    label: string;
    value: number;
}

interface DownlineProgressBarProp {
    data: Data
}

type DownlineProgressBarProps = [
    DownlineProgressBarProp,
    DownlineProgressBarProp,
    DownlineProgressBarProp?
];
```

Comment: ok, I think it is a step forward, but now I have an issue:
`Type '{ data: { key: string; label: string; value: number; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DownlineProgressBarProps'.
  Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DownlineProgressBarProps'`

Comment: Yup, this is actually because your type `DownlineProgressBarProps` expects an object with a property named `data` of type Data as above. 
I wanted to show the core of the solution without too much sugar — which adds confusion — thinking that you can adapt it. If not I can complete the answer

Comment: I will be grateful if you can complete the answer and "open my eyes" :)

Comment: @Baldini you can use more correct but also  more verbose notation: `type DownlineProgressBarProps = [ Data, Data ] | [ Data, Data, Data];`

Comment: @Baldini Ok, see the addition :)

Comment: @MichaelP.Bazos, still `Property 'data' does not exist on type 'DownlineProgressBarProps'.` :( 
I think that I'm doint sth wrong here: `DownlineProgress = ({data}: DownlineProgressBarProps) => {`

Comment: `export const DownlineProgress = (props: DownlineProgressBarProps)`

Comment: `data` is indeed not a property of the props type (a collection), but it is a property of a single item from that collection. You get that issue because you're using destructuring, but you specified the type of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom function for the same it would be the correct way.

```
  const propTypes = {
    data: arrayOfLength.bind(null, 2)
  }

  const arrayOfLength = (expectedLength, props, propName, componentName) => {
    const arrayPropLength = props[propName].length

    if (arrayPropLength !== expectedLength) {
      return new Error(
        `Invalid array length ${arrayPropLength} (expected ${expectedLength}) for prop ${propName} supplied to ${componentName}. Validation failed.`
      )
    }
  }
```